# The Output of this python code is not what I am expecting

Tags: python, data-analysis, data-mining

I'm a new CE student and I wanted to make a python program that read the input from a text file and give me the output in a text file.
in this program I want it to take the input line by line and give me the frequency of its contents.
but its not accurate and has a messy output.
I was hoping you can help me.

this is the output it gives me :

```plaintext
 'Kidney Beans': 5
 'Onion': 4
: 4
['Milk': 3
 'Yogurt']: 3
 'Kidney Beans'  'Yogurt']: 3
  'Yogurt']: 3
```

this is the output I want :

```plaintext
Kidney Beans: 5
Onion: 4
Eggs: 4
Yogurt: 3
Yogurt, Kidney Beans: 3
Milk: 3
Kidney Beans, Milk: 3
```

this is my python code :

```python
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, name, frequency, parent):
        self.name = name
        self.frequency = frequency
        self.parent = parent
        self.link = None
        self.children = {}
    
    def increment(self, frequency):
        self.frequency += frequency

# Update the tree with filtered transactions
def update_tree(items, node, header_table):
    first_item = items[0]
    if first_item in node.children:
        node.children[first_item].increment(1)
    else:
        new_node = TreeNode(first_item, 1, node)
        node.children[first_item] = new_node

        # Link the new node to nodes having the same item name
        if not header_table[first_item][1]:
            header_table[first_item][1] = new_node
        else:
            update_header(new_node, header_table[first_item][1])

    if len(items) > 1:
        update_tree(items[1:], node.children[first_item], header_table)

# Update the header table to link similar items
def update_header(node_to_test, target_node):
    while target_node.link is not None:
        target_node = target_node.link
    target_node.link = node_to_test

# Find frequent itemsets
def mine_tree(header_table, min_support, prefix, freq_items):
    sorted_items = [v[0] for v in sorted(header_table.items(), key=lambda p: (p[1][0], p[0]))]
    for base_pat in sorted_items[::-1]:  # Start from bottom up
        new_freq_set = prefix.copy()
        new_freq_set.add(base_pat)
        freq_items.append((new_freq_set, header_table[base_pat][0]))
        
        # Find prefixes
        cond_patt_bases = find_prefix_path(base_pat, header_table[base_pat][1])
        # Create conditional tree
        cond_tree, head = create_tree(cond_patt_bases, min_support)

        if head is not None:
            mine_tree(head, min_support, new_freq_set, freq_items)

# Ascend tree
def ascend_tree(node, prefix_path):
    if node.parent is not None:
        prefix_path.append(node.name)
        ascend_tree(node.parent, prefix_path)

# Find prefix path
def find_prefix_path(base_pat, treeNode):
    cond_pats = {}
    while treeNode is not None:
        prefix_path = []
        ascend_tree(treeNode, prefix_path)
        if len(prefix_path) > 1:
            cond_pats[frozenset(prefix_path[1:])] = treeNode.frequency
        treeNode = treeNode.link
    return cond_pats

# Create the FP-growth tree
def create_tree(transactions, min_support):
    header_table = {}
    for transaction in transactions:
        for item in transaction:
            header_table[item] = header_table.get(item, 0) + 1

    # Remove items not meeting minimum support
    for k in list(header_table):
        if header_table[k] < min_support:
            del(header_table[k])

    freq_item_set = set(header_table.keys())
    if len(freq_item_set) == 0:
        return None, None

    # Initialize header table
    for k in header_table:
        header_table[k] = [header_table[k], None]

    tree_root = TreeNode('Null Set', 1, None)
    for transaction in transactions:
        transaction_filtered = [item for item in transaction if item in freq_item_set]
        transaction_filtered.sort(key=lambda item: header_table[item][0], reverse=True)
        if transaction_filtered:
            update_tree(transaction_filtered, tree_root, header_table)
    return tree_root, header_table

# Load data from file
def load_data(file_path):
    dataset = []
    with open('InputData.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            transaction = line.strip().split(',')  # Adjust delimiter if necessary
            dataset.append(transaction)
    return dataset

# Main function to run FP-growth algorithm
def fpgrowth():
    file_path = "InputData.txt"  # Specify your dataset file name
    transactions = load_data(file_path)
    min_support = int(input("Please enter the minimum support: "))

    # Build the FP-growth tree
    tree, header_table = create_tree(transactions, min_support)

    # Find frequent itemsets
    freq_items = []
    if tree is not None:
        mine_tree(header_table, min_support, set(), freq_items)

    # Write the frequent itemsets to the output file
    output_file_name = "frequent_itemsets.txt"
    with open(output_file_name, 'w') as f:
        for itemset, support in sorted(freq_items, key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True):
            f.write(f"{' '.join(itemset)}: {support}\n")
    print(f"Frequent itemsets written to {output_file_name}")

# Run the FP-growth algorithm
fpgrowth()
```

and this is my Database :

```plaintext
dataset = [ ['Milk', 'Onion', 'Nutmeg', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs', 'Yogurt'], ['Dill', 'Onion', 'Nutmeg', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs', 'Yogurt'], ['Milk', 'Apple', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs'], ['Milk', 'Unicorn', 'Corn', 'Kidney Beans', 'Yogurt'], ['Corn', 'Onion', 'Onion', 'Kidney Beans', 'Ice cream', 'Eggs'] ]
```

I tried many things such as ChatGPT and asking my colleagues but its all the same.

Comment: _and this is my Database_ Do you man that is the literal content of the InputData.txt file, or do you mean that is the output of calling `load_data()` ?

Comment: @JohnGordon no its the content of m file that I'm giving it to the code.
named "InputData"

Comment: In `def fpgrowth():` comment of the 1st two lines. Set ``` transactions = [['Milk', 'Onion', 'Nutmeg', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs', 'Yogurt'],
                    ['Dill', 'Onion', 'Nutmeg', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs', 'Yogurt'],
                    ['Milk', 'Apple', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs'],
                    ['Milk', 'Unicorn', 'Corn', 'Kidney Beans', 'Yogurt'],
                    ['Corn', 'Onion', 'Onion', 'Kidney Beans', 'Ice cream', 'Eggs']]``` Respond to the prompt ```Please enter the minimum support: 3``` and the output will be as expected. So the problem appears to be in ``` load_data().

Comment: Your code is not reading the input file properly.  You're not accounting for the quote marks and square brackets `[ ]`.  It seems you are expecting the text file to be treated as python code.

Comment: Also, the input file content as posted has exactly one line, but the code seems to expect that it will have more than one line.  Which is correct?

Comment: _I tried many things such as ChatGPT and asking my colleagues_ Are your colleagues professional python developers?

Comment: @JohnGordon so what should I do?

Comment: @JohnGordon no here its a one line thing.. normally it has more then that

Comment: Either adjust the `load_data()` function so it properly accounts for those characters, or adjust the input file so it contains what the `load_data()` function expects.

Comment: @JohnGordon no they are not professional python developers

Comment: Are you familiar with the `json` library? The `dataset` you  provided can be stored and retrieved using `json`.

Comment: @Carl_M no I'm not

Comment: Can you use libraries for your assignment?  `ast.literal_eval()` can be used on the data after the `=`, so something like `dataset = ast.literal_eval(line.split('=')[1])` would parse the data into a list.  JSON won't work because of the single quotes.  The line is Python syntax so `literal_eval` will work.

Comment: @MarkTolonen yeah we can use anything.. how does ` literal_eval() `work?
and how should i use it in my code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `load_data()` function is expecting a different file format than what you actually have.

Try replacing the input file with these contents:

```
Milk,Onion,Nutmeg,Kidney Beans,Eggs,Yogurt
Dill,Onion,Nutmeg,Kidney Beans,Eggs,Yogurt
Milk,Apple,Kidney Beans,Eggs
Milk,Unicorn,Corn,Kidney Beans,Yogurt
Corn,Onion,Onion,Kidney Beans,Ice cream,Eggs
```

Comment: the answer you provided is correct.
but my issue is that with the type of input I provided its not working.
can you help me with this type of input ?
```lang-plaintext
dataset = [
['Milk', 'Onion', 'Nutmeg', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs', 'Yogurt'],
['Dill', 'Onion', 'Nutmeg', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs', 'Yogurt'],
['Milk', 'Apple', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs'],
['Milk', 'Unicorn', 'Corn', 'Kidney Beans', 'Yogurt'],
['Corn', 'Onion', 'Onion', 'Kidney Beans', 'Ice cream', 'Eggs']
]
```

Comment: @emad Why is your input file in that format?  Why is it trying to look like python code?  That's a silly format to use.

Comment: @emad that may be the whole purpose of the assignment, to teach you to parse arbitrary input.  Think about the input and how it relates to your desired output, and what parts of the input are necessary to accomplish it.  This answer simply proves that the rest of your program works.

Comment: @JohnGordon this is the input sample my assignment  is giving me.. it has to be like this apparently.

Comment: @emad If you really must use that input format, then your `load_data()` function should be a lot more complex.  It should pay attention to the `[ ]` characters to know where each list begins and ends, and it should strip away the quote marks.

Comment: @JohnGordon. Given the structure shown is there a reason for not suggesting solving using json?

Comment: @Carl_M I suppose one could use json, after removing `dataset =` from the front of the string.  However, if the entire point of this exercise is for the student to write their own basic data parser, then of course using json would not be appropriate.

Comment: @Carl_M Also, json requires double quotes around strings, instead of single quotes, so the file contents could not be used exactly as shown.

Answer (score 0):

In comments any library can be used.  Here's an implementation using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse the Python syntax in the input:

```py
import ast

# Load data from file
def load_data(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        return ast.literal_eval(f.read().split('=')[1])
```

Replacing only the `load_data` function in the OP's code gives:

```
Please enter the minimum support: 3
Frequent itemsets written to frequent_itemsets.txt
```

**frequent_itemsets.txt:**

```
Kidney Beans: 5
Onion: 4
Eggs: 4
Yogurt: 3
Kidney Beans Yogurt: 3
Milk: 3
Kidney Beans Milk: 3
```

Comment: what if I couldn't use any libraries.. do you know the algorithm?

Comment: @emad Why reinvent the wheel?  You'd have to write a parser.

Comment: apparently we have to reinvent the wheel.. the algorithm that I created is working.. my only issue is that it cant read it well from Input file and it doesn't have the output it should..

Comment: @emad If you just use the `ast` module, then you can use my `load_data` implementation as a replacement.